# Doctrine Unknown column type "Date" requested

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I have a project in symfony2 where I want to map an entity class to the database, but executing `php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force` gives me following error:

> [Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException] Unknown column type "Date" requested.
>   Any Doctrine type that you use has to  be registered with
>   \Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::addType(). You can get a lis t of all the
>   known types with \Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::getTypeMap(). If t his
>   error occurs during database introspection then you might have forgot
>   t o register all database types for a Doctrine Type. Use
>   AbstractPlatform#reg isterDoctrineTypeMapping() or have your custom
>   types implement Type#getMapp edDatabaseTypes(). If the type name is
>   empty you might have a problem with the cache or forgot some mapping
>   information.

What am I doing wrong here? I have following annotations in my entity class:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="date", type="Date")
 */
private $date;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to use lowercase type `date`. Full list of doctrine types see [here](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/basic-mapping.html#doctrine-mapping-types).

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="date")
 */
private $date;
```